# How to find the version for the Oracle Forms Compiler in Linux

Tags: linux, forms, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm trying to find the version of the Oracle Forms Builder and/or Forms Compiler in a linux installation. I know it's an Oracle Forms 11g install, but I need the specific version.

In the Windows Desktop version of Forms Builder, this can be achieved by accessing the "Help" -> "About Forms Builder..." menu. Which produces the following information:
[image: Forms Builder About Window]

But how can this be this achieved in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the answer was quite simple. If you have access to the forms builder command or the batch command, just running it without any parameter produces the version information. For instance, in our set up, we where using the **frmcmp_batch** command to compile the forms. So just running the command alone produces the version information which looks something like this:

```
Forms 11 (Form Compiler) Version 11.1.2.2.0 (Production)

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

PL/SQL Version 11.1.0.7.0 (Production)
Oracle Procedure Builder V11.1.2.2.0 - Production
Oracle Virtual Graphics System Version 11.1.2.2.0 (Production)
Oracle Multimedia Version 11.1.2.2.0 (Production)
Oracle Tools Integration Version 11.1.2.2.0 (Production)
Oracle Tools Common Area Version 11.1.2.2.0
Oracle CORE     11.1.0.7.0      Production
```